# HUAWEI mobile phone push delay too long sometimes, is there any solution？

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

Due to project reasons, there are certain requirements for push time, but now there are occasionally problems with this.Is there any way to reduce the time？

Comment: What do you mean "push time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the cause of the delay according to the following methods, thereby reducing the delay:

1.Try to choose to push when the user's APP is online. If the user is offline, the message will be cached, and it will be discarded if it exceeds the time, causing a delay.

2. Do not push the server across regions.
3. Try to avoid the peak service period. When the pressure on Huawei servers is too much, there will be a delay.
4. Test the network problem and increase the network speed, otherwise it will cause delay.
5. It is recommended that developers test the test platform before pushing the message. If the test is not delayed, it is a problem of the developer server.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more information to really figure out the problem, but more generally there are a couple things you can consider first:

1. Do you use a lot of token-based/topic-based etc so that the system need more time to schedule?
2. Is your data storage location configured in the console suitable for your app's operating regions?
3. Do you send a lot of push messages in a short time?

If the above are all optimized and it's still slow you may need to contact their support to investigate if there's any problem